# Remove rows from a multi index DataFrame using a conditional argument referencing an indexed value in another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame containing static information on a set of components. One of the fields is an 'inclusionDate'.

I have another multi-index DataFrame containing a time-series of values for these components, where index levels are 0=date, 1=subAssetClass, 2=indexId.

I want to remove the rows in the multi-index DataFrame which are less than the respective components 'inclusionDate'.

I am struggling to find a solution without a for loop over 500k rows for 100 components.

```py
componentStatic['includeDate'].head()

indexId
23287   2002-01-31
24282   2005-02-18
19006   2002-01-31
16581   2002-01-31
19011   2002-01-31
Name: includeDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]

signal.head(20)
                                    return
date       subAssetClass   indexId                  
2002-01-31 Precious Metals 7973     0.0809176     
                           7974    -0.0668868     
           Commodities     7975     -0.162488    
                           7976     -0.277053     
           Equities        24282    -0.162488
```

What I expecting: for indexId 24282 the includeDate is 2005-02-18. I want to remove all rows prior to the includeDate where 24282 appears in the signal DataFrame, i.e. the last entry.

I need to run this operation on the signal DataFrame for all ~100 components in the componentStatic DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

Check with `get_level_values` and `map`

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(0)<df.index.get_level_values(2).map(componentStatic['includeDate'])]
```